# Here i want to input fields dynamically

Tags: php, codeigniter, dynamic

I want to get the input field dynamically based on the Number of field names in the database post your codes.

**view page**

```
<?php echo form_open('index.php/product/save_edit') ?>
    <?php echo form_hidden('id',$product['id']) ?>
    <div class="values">Name</div><br>
    <?php echo form_input('name',$product['name']) ?>
    <br>

    <div class="values">Lenssensor</div><br>
    <?php echo form_input('lenssensor',$product['lenssensor']) ?>
    <br>

    <div class="values">Price</div><br>
    <?php echo form_input('price',$product['price']) ?>
    <br>

    <div class="values">Thickness</div><br>
    <?php echo form_input('thick',$product['thick']) ?>
    <br><br><br>
     <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?> 
    <br>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Controller edit code function**

```
public function edit(){
  $this->load->database();
  $this->load->model('product_model');
  $data['product'] = $this->product_model->product($this->uri->segment(3))[0];
  $this->load->view('product_edit',$data);
}
```

Comment: your question is unclear. Pls clarify it

Comment: i need to get the field names from db with as much input fields

Comment: do a foreach on your product_model properties

Comment: @coder how to change the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to following

```
    <?php echo form_open('index.php/product/save_edit')

         $obj = new $this->product_model;
         foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
         if($key == "id"){
         echo form_hidden($key,$value) 
          }
           else{    
         echo "<div class='values'>$key</div><br>".form_input($key,$value)."<br>" ;
        }
} ?>

                <br><br><br>
         <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?> 
        <br>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```